# finding it difficult to install or even use django-braces

Tags: python, django

So i have a few problems on code. Im trying to dispaly success error message using Mixins but i have trying installing django-braces to my venv but it doesnt work, im using class based views and the regualr mixin imports works fine.
I tried using FormMessageMixin
i also did 'from braces.views import FormMessageMixin, it is still not working. any body come accros this issue yet

alo -m pip install django-braces doesnt work. i am somwhat new to class based views and django in general Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error messages when running `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Try `pip install django-braces` when  using  `-m` you have to specify a specific interpreter I guess you didn't

Comment: @DavidSchultz yes the site was going great till i started trying to use django-braces. now it doesnt work anymore

Comment: @monim i did tried bot pip install and -m pip install both failed

Comment: Please give us also the contents of the error messages you get.

Comment: @DavidSchultz Its alot but the last line is "  from braces.views import FormMessagesMixin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'braces'"

Comment: Okay, then the most likely thing is that your pip is operating on a different virtual environment than the one you are using to run Django. Does the package django-braces show up when you type `pip list`? And in the *same* command line, please enter the python interpreter and look at the output after typing `import sys; sys.executable`: Is the path that is shown there identical to the python executable *within* your virtual environment?

Comment: There is no Django-braces on pip list